# R -- trying to merge data frames with unequal dimensions

Tags: r

I have two data frames.

Dataframe 1

```
NAME    TWEET COUNT
Jill    304
Sara    243
Bill    3022
```

Dataframe 2

```
NAME    SEX     STATE
Bill    Male    IL
Jane    Female  MI
Steve   Male    CA
Sara    Female  IN
Jill    Female  AL
```

I want to

1. Create a new column in dataframe 2
2. Plug in the values in dataframe 1 in the rows for which the names match dataframe 1.
3. Fill in the empty spaces in the column with NA

I don't understand how to do the matching part. How do I compare two dataframe columns with unequal lists?

Comment: Please show small reproducible example and expected output.  It seems like a simple `merge` will do it

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Take a look at the dplyr package.  You will need to perform a table join.  Most likely a left or full join, but check the documentation for to be sure.

Comment: @Dave2e these are dataframes though, does that make a difference?

Comment: This is a simple merge, `merge(df2, df1, by = "NAME", all.x=TRUE)`

Comment: Since "NAME" is common in both data frames you can drop the `by = "NAME"`